# reinterpret_cast of signed int reference

Tags: c++, integer, reinterpret-cast

Why is the result `4294967292` instead of `-4` even when both integer types are signed?

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int & i)
{
    i = -4;
}

int main()
{
    long long i = 0;
    f(reinterpret_cast<int &>(i));
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Signed integer represenation, endianess, you name it. That's why you don't use `reinterpret_cast` like that.

Comment: @StoryTeller I know `reinterpret_cast` is bad, but why this happens?

Comment: It's not "bad", it just does something that you can't reliably predict on every architecture. You take a reference to a big object, and than treat it like a reference to a small object. You have no guarantee that you'll manipulate the "correct" part of the larger object.

Comment: I'd just like to add, that `reinterpret_cast` is useful when you are using C code that implements OO styled inheritance by having two structs contain the same fields at the beginning. The two types are separate as far as the type system goes, but you may often need to cast pointers of the two structs from one to the other and back.  `reinterpret_cast` is the only cast that can do that.

Comment: Do you mean why does this happen to be the result on your platform? Or do you mean why is this permitted by the C++ standard? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`long long` seems to be 64-bit and `int` 32-bit number on your architecture. You're using 32-bit integer references, so you only modified the less significant half (you're evidently compiling on an ordinary x86 machine, which uses [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and two's complement for signed integer representation).

The sign bit, as well as the more significant half are all `0`s (as initialized). It would have to be `1`s to print the same negative value:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100
^                                       ^
sign bit of long long                   sign bit of int
```

[`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) only guarantees that you get back your `int` with another `reinterpret_cast`, so you either print it as `int`, or use `long long &` parameter.

Comment: .. and -4 and 4294967292 have the same binary representation.. just pointing it out.